k-fold cross-validation for extremely imbalanced classes?
I'm doing a classification project with two imbalanced classes.  I'm aware that for k-fold cross-validation in Python one can use the option "stratify" when making the splits to account for this.  However, my data is very imbalanced: I have 60 "1"s out of over 15,000 observations.  Someone told me k-fold cross-validation might not be appropriate in this case, even with the stratify option, but I wanted to get some feedback.  Should I still use k-fold cross-validation in my case?

assuming you do something like 5 fold CV, you're only going to be evaluating the model on 16 positive cases.  That doesn't sound like a lot in which to measure things like sensitivity, specificity, or whatever other metrics you use.  If you use fewer folds, the number of 1s in the holdout case will increase but you will have fewer to fir your model on.  You're stuck between a rock and a hard place in this case.  Is it possible to get more data?

Hi Demetri, thanks for answering!  Maybe it's possible to get more data.  The data is all the bills introduced in the 118th Congress of the U.S. and the positive cases are whether the bill became law.  To get more data I'd have to look at other sessions of Congress.

+1 to pevious comments. What are you using the CV for? AUC should still work. Maybe you can oversample true 1 in the holdout set.

@DirkN, are you asking what model I'm testing with CV?  I wondered about oversampling but because the classes are so imbalanced wouldn't it be bad to have so many repetitions of the 1 class?
